# Класс от класса с generics

Tags: java, generics

Есть метод

```
public Class<MyClass<String>> getClassType() {
}
```

Как вернуть нужный класс с женериком? Если возвращать **MyClass.class**, то ругается на несоответствие типов, так как вернуть требуется **Class<MyClass< String>>**, а возвращается просто **MyClass.class**

Comment: Дженерик нужно указывать там, куда возвращаете. Дженерики это входные параметры, а не возвращаемые типы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению только кастить.

```
return (Class<MyClass<String>>)(Object)MyClass.class;
```

Второй каст нужен чтобы показать компилятору кто в доме хозяин.